# Summing Elapsed Time Based on Two Criteria - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Like the title says, I'm trying to sum elapsed time based on two criteria in Excel (2016). Specifically the elapsed time of a phone call based on user and call type, examples below.

The actual data is similar to this [Dummy Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE9up.png) where there would be a list of users, *Full name*, the duration of a given call, *Duration*, and the type of call, *Call Type*.

The expected output would be in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwzJO.png) format; however, the main focus for my issue falls under the *Total Time* column, and its worth noting that the red times shown were hand-done as these are the cause of this post.

As for the logic I'm using at the moment to try and get these results, it's `=SUMIFS(C2:C16, B2:B16, G2, D2:D16, H2&"*")` where C2"C16 is the *Duration* column, B2:B16 is the *Full Name* column, G2 is "Generic User", D2:D16 is *Call Type*, and H2&"*" comes to *Local**, worth a note is the wildcard, as there are two types of Internal and Local calls, but I'm just trying to get all Local and all Internal without distinction of sub-types.

Additional notes for the cell formats are that the *Duration* and *Total Time* columns are set for [h]:mm:ss, but I've also tried other time and number formats which didn't change the outcome.

So at this point I'm just spinning my wheels as I've Googled and looked into different ways to go about this, such as different cell formats, cell operations/logic and so on, and I'm just unsure where the issue may actually be, so any suggestions or help would be very appreciated.

Edit 1: Including a link for the [file](https://file.io/LdgYF2svoL3Q)

Comment: Your `G2` is not matching the contents of `Full Name`. Hence your results. Prove this with `=g2=b2`. If that doesn't return `TRUE` that is your problem.  Maybe a `<LF>` between the words?

Comment: Try Pivot Tables. I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, How so? G2 is the is referencing the cell with the "Generic User" in it. Does it have to be explicit?

Comment: have a try, `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C2:C16,B2:B16,"*"&TRIM(G2)&"*",D2:D16,{"*Local*","*Internal*"}))`

Comment: If g2 matches, your formula works as is.

Comment: Actually, you could have a mismatch in your other criteria, but the logic of your formula is sound, so there must be something about your data not showing in your example.

Comment: @Can.U Trying your formula resulted in two outcomes. For the "Local" type calls it comes out to 0:00:00; however, for "Internal" types it came to 0:54:40, and I'm not sure why. The format these cells, as well as those in the "Duration" are set to [h]:mm:ss, and for the "Full name" & "Call Type" those are set as _text_

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Would this be what you were meaning when you say theres something about the data?

Comment: @Azurn The data is the information you have stored. Something isn't matching with the values you are trying to match. Without examining data that can reproduce the problem, I cannot help you further. Perhaps reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then editing your question to provide the example, would be helpful.

Comment: @Azurn Upload your excel file to the online document, and explain the results you need, you can get effective help faster.

Comment: @Can.U Uploaded a dummy file. The quick explanation for results is that I'm trying to sum all the call durations under the "Duration" column based on the user and general call type (Local/Internal), so all Local* calls for Generic User A would be summed, similarly as all Internal* calls to the same user and displayed under the "Agent Calls" sheet. If that makes sense?

Comment: As I wrote initially, your problem is that *G2 is not matching the contents of Full Name*. Reviewing your sheet, `G2 = "Generic User A"`, and  `Full Name = "Generic User"`  You would need to remove the ` A` from `G2`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Correct and I should have corrected that as you suggested, as far as "Sheet1" goes being a dummy sheet, the main focus would be "Agent Calls" Which has a similar setup, but still returns 0:00:00 after following the suggested formula above. I apologize for that, with that being said thought would you be able to take a look at my logic on "Agent Calls" sheet in F3 and explain my misunderstanding or fault for it not working properly?

Comment: It appears you have an accepted answer, so I will bow out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J2  This is for your reference only.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$16=G$2)*(C$2:C$16)*ISNUMBER(FIND(H2,D$2:D$16)))
```